# PHP functions to parse multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I run a query and`fetchAll()`

```
$query = "SELECT uid, kill_count FROM users WHERE curmid=:mid AND status='1'";
...
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

that returns this array:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [uid] => 105 [fcount] => 1 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [uid] => 106 [fcount] => 2 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [uid] => 107 [fcount] => 0 ) 
 [3] => Array ( [uid] => 108 [fcount] => 1 ) 
 [4] => Array ( [uid] => 109 [fcount] => 1 ) 
)
```

I have a loop that I want to run it through that is basically:

```
$problist = array();
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 0) {
        array_push($problist, $key, $key, $key, $key, $key);
    } elseif ($value == 1) {
        array_push($problist, $key, $key, $key);
    } elseif ($value >= 2) {
        $problist[] = $key;
    }
}
```

Of course, that loop doesn't work as it doesn't reference the proper values in the array.  The output I'm looking for, in this hypothetical, is:  `$problist =`

```
array(15) { 
[0]=> string(3) "105" 
[1]=> string(3) "105" 
[2]=> string(3) "105" 
[3]=> string(3) "106" 
[4]=> string(3) "107" 
[5]=> string(3) "107" 
[6]=> string(3) "107" 
[7]=> string(3) "107" 
[8]=> string(3) "107" 
[9]=> string(3) "108" 
[10]=> string(3) "108" 
[11]=> string(3) "108"
[12]=> string(3) "109" 
[13]=> string(3) "109" 
[14]=> string(3) "109" 
}
```

I've read and tinkered and then read and tinkered cannot figure out which php functions to use to make this work.  I've tried `end()`, `reset()`, `array_shift()`, and others.  It is certainly possible that in my ignorance I wasn't using them correctly.  Thanks for the help.

[Perhaps there is even a better way to format my query?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$problist = array();
foreach ($row as $value) {
    if ($value['fcount'] == 0) {
        array_push($problist, $value['uid'], $value['uid'], $value['uid'], $value['uid'], $value['uid']);
    } elseif ($value['fcount'] == 1) {
        array_push($problist, $value['uid'], $value['uid'], $value['uid']);
    } elseif ($value['fcount'] >= 2) {
        $problist[] = $value['uid'];
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't factor in `fcount` at all.

Comment: Hehe... Copy/Paste sucks. :)

Comment: Much appreciated.  You practically answered my othe question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082020/select-a-user-according-to-set-probability      Feel free to actually answer it for credit.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through entire resultset, so `$value` is an array looking like:

```
$value = array(
    'uid' => 105,
    'fcount' => 1
);
```

So in your code you should use `$value['uid']` instead of `$key` and `$value['fcount']` instead of `$value`.